# Is there a way to globalize variables in C functions?

Tags: c, global-variables, global

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    void Arithmetic (int num1, int num2)
    {
        // Sum
        float sum;
        
        sum = num1+num2;
        sum = (float) sum; // return this
        
        // Difference
        float diff;
        
        diff = num1+num2;
        diff = (float) diff; // return this
        
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*After that, I write more arithmetic operations, but I figured it would be too long to write as an example, so I just wrote `// ...`*

I don't know how to return multiple variables at once, so is it possible to globalize these? And if not, are there alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: Several things here: 
1: declaring functions inside of others may be accepted by the compiler  but is very bad practice.
2: To return several values, you could either pass them by reference (a pointer to the variable passed as argument, which you modify in the function) or use a struct, or declare your variables as global outside the function.
3: Why not create two functions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Using global variables instead of return values is not a good idea. They are not thread safe and should be avoided. You should also be aware that nested function definitions is not a standard C feature but only accepted due to compiler extensions. You might want to look into structurs for returning multiple values.

Comment: Re "*declaring functions inside of others may be accepted by the compiler but is very bad practice*", and non-standard.

Comment: Use a struct and declare a new combined datatype. Like:

`#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _my_values{
    float sum;
    float diff;
} MY_VALUES;

MY_VALUES test_print(){
    MY_VALUES test_values;
    test_values.sum = 2.0;
    test_values.diff = 1.0;
    return test_values;
}

int main()
{
    printf("sum=%f, diff=%f\n", test_print().sum, test_print().diff);
    return 0;
}`